# App Store reports updates but no updates are available

Tags: ios-appstore, software-update

It's one day that the AppStore icon and application of my iPhone 5S reports that there is one update to be done, but, in fact, no updates are available.
I already tried to switch the iPhone off and on or reopen the app, but nothing changes.
 Why does this happened, and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219156/ios-app-store-will-not-update-apps-unless-the-update-button-is-pressed-many-time perhaps?

Comment: @bmike Actually I just waited one week, and the problem solved automatically. I don't really know what happened and how it has been fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Why not why can't they update it seems like this is a scam so that apple can get more money what do you think

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please make sure that your answer actually addresses the question posted by the OP.  For more information on what makes a good answer, please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  - From Review -