# App updates require many retries to install

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I think this started with iOS 9. App updates often seem to fail quickly and require multiple presses of either the `UPDATE` button or the `Update All` link at the top. This happens both on iPad (4) and iPhone (6S). It sort of looks like the connection to the App Store quickly fails but later works - it is unlikely to fail once the progress bar has started.

There are a few tricks that help (repeated taps of the buttons; so many taps that the app store cache clears; killing and restarting the app store; restarting the device). However, the problem keeps coming back. It seems worse on the iPad, which is sometimes left unattended for a few days or a week. Later there are many pending updates.

It also often confuses pending updates with installed updates - the button changes from `UPDATE` to `OPEN` and the `Update All` button is present but greyed out. For the first ~half second this is not the case, so you can still install the updates if you are quick.

This sounds very similar to [iOS App Store will not update apps unless the Update button is pressed many times](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219156/ios-app-store-will-not-update-apps-unless-the-update-button-is-pressed-many-time). However, in this case there are no failure messages and resetting network settings has not fixed the issue. Also, iOS updates never fail for me.

Comment: I am also facing this issue after 10.0.1 update, just read it somewhere the bug has been fixed and will be patched in iOS 10.1 update.

Comment: Do you have a reference? Seems doubtful that it goes unfixed in the major release and then gets fixed in a minor, doesn't it?

Comment: ,Unable to fetch the original post , however Please go through comments in the following thread https://9to5mac.com/2016/09/23/ios-10-0-2-lighting-headphone-bug-iphone-7/
Check Tony Turner's response to Tavish's `Does the beta from yesterday include these fixes?` comment.

Comment: I think @onkar is referring to this comment thread: https://9to5mac.com/2016/09/23/ios-10-0-2-lighting-headphone-bug-iphone-7/#comment-2914077523 It's not clear whether there's only one bug here (not updating automatically vs failing manually vs mis-identifying updates as done), but potentially that is indeed a fix.

Comment: This is not fixed in 10.1. I haven't tried 10.1.1 yet.

Comment: I am still facing the issue on 10.1.1 on iPhone 5s